# Identify Columns that meet where clause condition in SQL query

Tags: sql-server

I need the names of the columns that meet the where clause condition in a sql query. Once I have the column names I can put them to further use.

Code:

```
Declare @sdate datetime
Declare @edate datetime
set @sdate='2018-01-01 00:00:00'
set @edate='2018-01-18 23:59:59'

select * from Upload Where

(Select CASE WHEN Step_1 >= @sdate and Step_1 <= @edate THEN 'Step_1') >= @sdate and 

(Select CASE WHEN Step_2 >= @sdate and Step_2 <= @edate THEN 'Step_2') >= @sdate

go
```

Comment: Your two conditions are identical?

Comment: Based on your query, it's always going to be the column `Step_1`, that's the only column that's being checked in your `WHERE` clause. Your question doesn't make any sense. Please try re-wording it and elaborating.

Comment: This makes no sense at all. Your case expression is returning a string "Step_1" which you are then comparing to a date. You have the exact same condition twice. And your case expression is missing "END". We need some details about what you are trying to do. Here is a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: Move your case statements to select part of the query e.g. `( CASE WHEN Step_1 >= @sdate and Step_1 <= @edate THEN 'Step_1'  WHEN /* something else tec. */ ELSE '' END ) AS MyColumns`

Comment: Dan/Larnu/Sean - this just a sample of the SQL, the entire sql is big and yes the second should say Step 2 instead of one so these are diff conditions.